# tsql query kill scenario

Tags: t-sql, signals, handler, kill

In our webapp, we have lots of queries running. Most of them reading data but some update queries with high priority might come. Since, we'd like to cancel read queries but when using KILL, I'd like the read query to return certain dataset result or execution result upon receiving cancel.

My intention is to mimic the behavior of signal in C programs for which a signal handler is invoked upon receiving a kill signal.

Is there any method to define an asynchrnous KILL signal handler for SPs?

Comment: Do not think there is any out of box solution. Check this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/541834/How-to-execute-multiple-long-running-SQL-Statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a fully tested answer.  But it is a bit more than just a comment.

One is to have dirty read (with nolock). 
This part is tested I do this all time. 
Build a large scalable app you need to resort to this and manage it.
A dirty read will not block an update. 
You can get that - a dirty read. 
A lot of people think a dirty read may get corrupt data. 
If you are updating smith to johnson the select is not going to get smison. 
The select is going to get smith and it will be immediately stale. 
But how is that worse then taking a read lock?
The read get smith and blocks the update.
Once the read locks are cleared it is updated. 
I would contend that blocking an update is also stale data.

If you are using reader I think you could pass the same cancellation token to each select and then just cancel the one token. 
But if may not process the CancellationToken until it read the row so it may not cancel a query a long running query that has not yet returned any rows.
[DbDataReader.ReadAsync Method (CancellationToken)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh223697(v=vs.110).aspx)

Or if you are not using reader look at
[SqlCommand.Cancel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.cancel.aspx)

As far as getting cancel to return alternate data.  I doubt SQL is going to do that.

Comment: Thanks Balm,What I exactly need is to distinguish between read queries that have been cancelled by updates by just examining the result set or the return value of SP execution

Comment: If it was an answer then indicate so by clicking the check.